# Optimal Way to Assign Most Popular Neighbor Variable in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-geometry

I've got a census block table in Postgres with the appropriate geom column and a string variable. All census blocks that have a population greater than 0 have an assignment for my string variable. Those that do not have any population have no assignment.

What is the optimal (in terms of query time) way to assign the most popular value of the neighboring census blocks to the center census block below? In simpler terms, how can I assign "A" to the center census block below because it's the most popular surrounding value?

st_touches seems to be running unrealistically long, perhaps I'm missing a where filter or some other tactic to decrease the run time of the query?

**Example Query:**

```
select 
    b.censusblock,
    b.countyname, 
    c.district,  
    c.censusblock as touch_block from bb
left join schema.districts c on st_touches(b.geom,c.geom) and c.countyname=b.countyname
```

[image: Example 1]

Comment: Could you add some code to the question so we can see what you've tried?

Comment: Added a code snippet that creates a useful end product when ran on a small number of rows but scales poorly

Comment: OK, obvious question, but you do have a spatial index on bb and districts geom columns? Also, you presumably need the max function and a group by in there to return the results as you describe them.

Comment: Yeah, we've got an index and the second query pulls the max function.

Comment: The 2nd query? It might help to include that. Also what does EXPLAIN show.